# Why do I have to label my second argument for a react native to swift bridged function

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native

Say I have the following Swift class:

```
@objc(ExampleClass)
  class ExampleClass: NSObject {
  init() {}
  @objc func exampleMethod(_ message: String, _ properties: [String: Any]? = nil) -> Void {}
}
```

And the following Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ExampleClass, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(exampleMethod:(NSString *)name (NSDictionary *)properties)
@end
```

Which I then call with the following React Native code:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'

NativeModules.ExampleClass.exampleMethod('example', {'hello': 'world'})
```

This results in the following error message:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:73 Exception 'exampleMethod: is not a recognized Objective-C method.' was thrown while invoking trackEvent on target SegmentTracker with params (
    "example",
        {
        hello = world;
    }
)
```

However, if I change the function signature to be labelled like so:

```
@objc func exampleMethod(_ message: String, withProperties properties: [String: Any]? = nil) -> Void {}
    }
```

And adjust the RCT_EXTERN_METHOD function like so:

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(exampleMethod:(NSString *)name withProperties:(NSDictionary *)properties)
```

Why does the second argument have to be labelled? Why doesn't the first one?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Swift and don't know anything about React Native but did you try `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(exampleMethod:(NSString *)name :(NSDictionary *)properties)`? The Objective-C method is `exampleMethod::`.

Comment: oooo I straight up misunderstood the Objective C syntax like a scrub! Thanks!

Comment: If you want to write that up, I will happily accept your response by the way